# If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of order $n$, which of these statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> 1. If $AB = B$, then $B$ is the identity matrix.
> 2. If matrix $A$ is reversible, then $ABA^{−1} = B$

Are these two equations true? Do square matrices have commutativity property? Can you explain me this? I'm beginner in math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is true.  Consider $A=I$.  Then $AB=B$ for any $B$.

For $2$, just consider a nondiagonal matrix which is diagonalizable.

One of the first things you will discover is that matrix multiplication isn't commutative.

For $2$, consider $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Try finding a different example.

Comment: Given the level of the question, I think OP might not know what "diagonalizable" means.

Comment: True.  It's the first example that came to mind.  I guess I'll try to produce a simpler one.